# Mobile web update hurts the eyes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

Using default Galaxy S4, kitkat, Samsung Internet browser (chrome/chromium based), the latest update (5/11/16) to the mobile website looks broken. (*Not on downloaded Chrome*)

[image]

Screen shot added. Title sizes are too big, pushing them onto a new line, breaking the flow and I know that's not as intended. The Paragraphs are also not filling the screen. Since they get pushed down, they align to the left edge, instead of the edge of the score/vote, so it's odd.

This is on both the main question list, and in the titles on an individual questions page. This also affects the answers.

[image]

This update went live at 4 pm est 5/11/16 or so, as it looked better before noon.

My User Agent (but changing it does not fix it):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SAMSUNG SM-G386T Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.6 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

#### Per other users, this is happening on iOS devices as well. [Misalignment in questions thread and questions on iPod Touch (global)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322902/)

To compare, how it looks on downloaded Chrome on same phone:

[image]

The User Agent for Chrome:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-G386T Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Comment: To confirm - this is the default android browser (aka aosp / Browser), not Chrome or other installed browser?

Comment: @oded correct default preinstalled. But it's not The Google Web kit based version found on froyo and earlier, it's chromium based.

Comment: No repro on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, Chrome 50 though...

Comment: Chrome downloaded looks okay, it's the Samsung browser that doesn't @bacon.

Comment: It's my first time seeing the new look -- it's the same on iOS's default Safari app. But it also looks the same on my Chrome. (Keep in mind, my phone and OS are both quite old, iphone 4S and iOS 7something).

Comment: thanks for reporting, i will investigate that. as a word of confirmation: yes, we've released slightly updated mobile skin for SE sites.

Comment: can you let me know what exactly version of Android do you have? i've tested it on few 4.x androids and it was ok..

Comment: Also, check if there's a setting that may modify appearance on browser, such as text size, font, zoom, etc. I don't know if it's only my feeling, but the font seems a little bit different on the screenshot... Or blame caching.

Comment: Pictures from an iPod Touch: http://postimg.org/gallery/331p76w5u/

Comment: @Paweł I posted this morning http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322902/ yet everything was fine till this morning and is like that throughout the entire network.

Comment: @Pawel android 4.4.2, on a Galaxy S4 variant. There is no scaling turned on.

Comment: American date format hurts the brain.

Comment: @Paweł I can repro this on Safari in iOS 8 as well.

Comment: @Oded: Just a note: In recent versions of Android, Chrome _is_ the default installed browser (OEM bloat excepted).

Comment: @Al not exactly. Google dropped the webkit based WebView browser for a chromium based, the open source chrome project, in 4.4 kitkat. Some manufactures continued to build a webkit browser, some used the chromium. Some, on the high end phones, decided to license chrome (just as they have to license the play store and other things). The S4 had both, S5 had full chrome only. Low end variants prefer chromium.

Comment: @cde: You'll notice I did make exception for OEM customization.

Comment: @Pawel  you changed this to status-planned, but it also seems to be fixed (no more large line breaks) at this time. Is it resolved?

Comment: Yes, it should be fixed now:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Pawel, fixed by the design team on 5/13. And it looks good now. Thanks.